# Why is yfinance suddenly giving back empty lists for previously functioning code?

Tags: python, stock, yfinance

I wrote a simple script that pulled some information on a list of tickers from the yahoo api using the yfinance python module.
This used to work and I could download and save relevant information on all tickers like historic prices, earnings reports, P/E, symbol, name, dividend, etc.

When I tried running the script today (which I do at regular intervals) all I got from yfinance were empty lists for all requests. As example we could take the code below:
input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

test = yf.Ticker("FB")
test.history()
```

output:

```
- FB: No data found, symbol may be delisted
Out[6]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume]
Index: []
```

This happens for all Tickers regardless (AAPL; AMZN; META; etc.)
Typically I make around 2000 requests over some 3 Hour period which has been fine for the last weeks. After not running it for approx. 1 week it does not work anymore though.

Is this just yfinance having some data or api problems or am I missing something?
Naturally restarting the kernel or re-installing / upgrading the yfinance module did not work.

I tried:

- restarted kernel
- upgraded yfinance using pip
- uninstalled and re-installed yfinance using pip
- deactivated antivirus
- checking different functions (history, info, earnings, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run the code in a jupyter notebook and it worked, so there had to be something wrong locally.
I solved it by restarting the computer and re-installing yfinance both over cmd and anaconda (which seems to have done the trick)

Comment: I don't know what `yfinance` is but, since your problem seems related to local installation, you should consider to start working with virtual environments ( https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/ )

Comment: Maybe I should. This appears to have been caused by re-installing the package on the wrong python environment... Actually I should have thought about that first.
I did not figure out why the previous installation stopped working though, I don't think the version changed ^^

Answer (score 0):

do that in the terminal:

```html
pip uninstall yfinance
```

be sure to delete it everywhere, I had python8 and 11 and I forgot to delete it in 11 and it didn't keep working, until I deleted it everywhere

and after reinstall it again, I suggest you specify the latest version (now 0.2.29):

```html
pip install yfinance==0.2.29
```

I'm pretty sure there was an error in the IDLE.